# Is there any relationship between the caste system and kundalis/gunas matching as it relates to marriage?

Tags: marriage, caste-system, kundali, gunas

I have heard/read that in some cases a marriage is forbidden on the basis of mismatching kundalis/gunas.

In some other cases it's forbidden because of caste incompatibility.

**Is there any relationship at all between the two practices?**

My understanding is that in the case of the caste system marriage among different castes is discouraged because some castes are deemed socially superior than others. This seems to be similar to the way marriage among different social classes is discouraged in western societies, e.g. millionaires rarely if ever marry a homeless person.

In the case of kundalis matching, the practice is based on the belief that astrological events can affect the marriage, hence certain matches are discouraged.

In the case of gunas matching, the practice seems to be based on the observation that different people have different behavioural tendencies, therefore it makes sense to discourage certain matches with undesirable people.

To me it seems that there's not relationship between them except for the fact that it's practiced by Indian people which also happen to practice Hinduism.

For that matter, it looks like none of these practices has any basis in the Hindu doctrine. They seem more like cultural practices specific to certain parts of India in which people also happen to practice Hinduism.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are many techniques used in *Jyotisha* for matching of horoscopes and neither of them prescribe to the prevalent caste-system. The most populist technique is the *Ashtakoota* system which focuses only on the behavorial patterns of both the parties.

These 8 factors are:

> *Varna*: this factor represents the spiritual development of the partners
>
> *Vasya*: this factor describes the degree to influence the other partner
>
> *Dina or Tara*: this factor measures the number of Nakshatras between the Moon positions of the partners
>
> *Yoni*: this factor measures sexual compatibility which we discussed on our Vedic sex horoscopes page
>
> *Graha Maitri*: this factor reflects the mental compatibility and affection. This score is about friendship
>
> *Gana*: this one is about the temperament and it's adviced to have the same temperament as your partner
>
> *Rasi*: this Kuta describes the relationship between the Moon signs (and Nakshatras) of the partners
>
> *Nadi*: this factor is about progeny and children. In some ways it also relates to health issues between the partners

You can read more here: http://www.cosmitec-astrological-compatibility-advice.com/ashtakoot-compatibility.html